# Executing a script before and after suspend/sleep on android

Tags: android, hook, resume, suspend

I would like to execute a script before my android device goes to sleep and also after it wakes up. I found out that there is something like a "early_suspend" hook for c, but I only want to execute a few lines of bash and I don't want to get into cross-compilation yet.

The background is the following: I have one of those crappy Archos tablets (with android 2.2) which sometimes doesn't reactivate the screen after suspend if the brightness of the screen is too low. My  a workaround would now be to increase the brightness before going to suspend and then restore it again after waking up.

On a sidenote: My device is rooted and I don't care how ugly the solution is as long as it works.

So is there some "early suspend" hook for shell code in android?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to wait until sleeping on a rooted ICS Galaxy Note. You can use "cat /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep" (and wait_for_fb_wake) to wait for the phone to sleep or wake.